# Spring Data Specifications - how can I filter objects by mulitple attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, predicates, jpa-criteria

I'm trying to implement searching of users by mulitple attributes.
Let's say, my Person has Name and Lastname. I want to type 'Michael Doe' and list all persons with this name and lastname. When I type only 'Michael', I want all Michaels and so on.

I tried to make it possible by using Predicates like:

```
private static Specification<UserEntity> containsTextInAttributes(List<String> text, List<String> attributes) {
    List<String> finalTextArray = text.stream().map(e -> "%"+e+"%").collect(Collectors.toList());
    return (root, query, builder) -> builder.or(root.getModel().getDeclaredSingularAttributes().stream()
            .filter(a -> attributes.contains(a.getName()))
            .map(a -> builder.or(finalTextArray.stream().map(e -> builder.like(root.get(a.getName()), e)).toArray(Predicate[]::new)))
            .toArray(Predicate[]::new)
    );
}

public static Specification<UserEntity> containsTextInAllAttributes(List<String> text) {
    return containsTextInAttributes(text, Arrays.asList("lastname", "firstname", "email", "phoneNumber"));
}
```

However, when I search 'Michael Doe" I have all Michaels and all with Lastname Doe. How can I solve my problem?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: May this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters) help?

Comment: Not quite since I want to use multiple words for filtering data.

Comment: Don't forget to accept\upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I.** `"Michael D", "firstName", "lastName"`, or `"mdoe@gmail", "email"`

```
public <T> Specification<T> dynamicLike(String likeValue, String... properties) {
    return (Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {

        Expression<String> concat = null;

        for (String property : properties) {
            if (concat == null) {
                concat = cb.concat("", root.get(property));
            } else {
                concat = cb.concat(concat, cb.concat(" ", root.get(property)));
            }
        }

        return cb.like(cb.lower(concat), "%" + likeValue.toLowerCase() + "%");
    };
}
```

**II.** `"Mic Do @gmail", "firstName", "lastName", "email"`

```
public <T> Specification<T> dynamicLike2(String value, String... properties) {
    return (Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {

        String[] values = value.split("\\s");
        int minNumber = Integer.min(values.length, properties.length);

        Predicate[] likes = new Predicate[minNumber];

        for (int i = 0; i < minNumber; i++) {
            likes[i] = cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(properties[i])), "%" + values[i].toLowerCase() + "%");
        }

        return cb.and(likes);
    };
}
```